# In CSS, set container size to X px, if child is smaller than X px, then reduce container size to child size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container for an element. I want to set a max height for the container holding the element, but have the container reduce its height if the element does not fill up the entirety of that size. Is it possible to do so through CSS?

Comment: It should be as simple as using `max-height: 300px; height: auto;`

Also your question should have some code to show what you've done so far.

Comment: What happens if the container has no child element?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `height: auto`. Please show your CSS and HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You just need to specify a minimum height on the parent.

```
.parent-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 6em;
}
p.child {
  // some code here
}
```

The parent will collapse to 6em if there is not enough text in your p html element to fill above 6em. N.B: you can use pixels or whatever if you haven't used ems.